# Changing color of specific value from list in wx.Choice

Tags: python, wxpython

Sorry to make this vague but I am writing a python code in which values from a list are being appended to a `wx.Choice` box. Within those values there are some correct ones and incorrect ones, I have made a distinction of which values are correct and which aren't within my code. I would like to show that these values are incorrect within the `wx.Choice` by making them red. I know that there are options such as `SetForegroundColour`, however I have not found an adequate way to do this within `wx.Choice`, anyone have any idea how I could do this?

Thank you!

Comment: I believe that it's not possible to access an individual item's attributes inside a wx.Choice.

Comment: I think that you are down in the guts of the widget itself. You could always colour the choice, once a choice has been made, although that probably isn't what you were after. This does beg the question, why would you include incorrect choices if they are invalid?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is another option, which you may find more to your liking, a `BitmapComboBox`, which is a combobox that displays a bitmap in front of the item in a list.

```
import wx
from wx.adv import BitmapComboBox   # Phoenix
#import wx.combo                    # wxpython Classic
class Myframe(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, None)
        pan = wx.Panel(self)
        valid_list = ["1111","22222","33333","44444"]
        invalid_list = ["5555","6666","77777","88888"]
        image = wx.Image("vvalid.png")
        valid_bmp = wx.BitmapFromImage(image)
        image = wx.Image("vinvalid.png")
        invalid_bmp = wx.BitmapFromImage(image)
        self.combo = BitmapComboBox(pan)           # Phoenix
        #self.combo = wx.combo.BitmapComboBox(pan)   #wxpython Classic
        for i in valid_list:
            self.combo.Append(i, bitmap=valid_bmp)
        for i in invalid_list:
            self.combo.Append(i, bitmap=invalid_bmp)
        self.combo.SetSelection(0)
        self.combo.Bind(wx.EVT_COMBOBOX, self.OnCombo)

    def OnCombo(self, event):
        print (self.combo.GetStringSelection())

if __name__ == "__main__":
    App = wx.App()
    Myframe().Show()
    App.MainLoop()
```

[image]

I have included code for both Phoenix and Classic wx, although using Phoenix you should replace `wx.BitmapFromImage` with just `wx.Bitmap`, it does currently let you get away with the old form.

Comment: This is an incredibly good solution! I didn't know you could use bitmaps in a combo box! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

As you are aware from the comments, what you are trying to do doesn't appear to be an easy option. However, you could use a `combotreebox` and place the valid and invalid choices in 2 different branches of the tree.

```
import wx
from wx.lib.combotreebox import ComboTreeBox
class Myframe(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, None)
        pan = wx.Panel(self)
        valid_list = ["1111","22222","33333","44444"]
        invalid_list = ["5555","6666","77777","88888"]
        self.combo = ComboTreeBox(pan)

        Valid = self.combo.Append('Valid Choices') # Add a root item
        for i in valid_list:
            self.combo.Append(i, parent=Valid) # Add childen to Valid Choices

        InValid = self.combo.Append('InValid Choices') # Add a root item
        for i in invalid_list:
            self.combo.Append(i, parent=InValid) # Add childen to InValid Choices
        self.combo.SetSelection(Valid)

        self.combo.Bind(wx.EVT_COMBOBOX, self.OnCombo)

    def OnCombo(self, event):
        print (self.combo.GetStringSelection())

if __name__ == "__main__":
    App = wx.App()
    Myframe().Show()
    App.MainLoop()
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for this alternate option. To answer your question about why I would want to present invalid values. it's because in this case "invalid" values means they are not equal to the other values in the list. But in some cases the value that is not equal might actually be the right value, so I want to keep the value in the list but indicate that it is different than the others.

Comment: I'm not sure if this is the appropriate place to put this comment but I've decided to indicate a difference by placing an asterisk next to the "invalid" items, thanks!

Comment: @steradian Simplicity is nearly always the best option